# android - button under a layout is still touchable

Tags: java, android, layout

I have a layout with 5 buttons and each of them has a **OnTouchListener** that slides a frame layout on screen (on top of the buttons) but after that all of my 5 buttons is still touchable.

> How to disable touch for views that is under other layouts such as
>   `FrameLayout` that filled with a fragment ?

```
<Button
    style="@style/tab_btn"
    android:background="@drawable/village_button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:text=""
    android:onClick="buttonPress"/>

<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar_btn"
    android:id="@+id/sidebar_btn4"
    android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-18dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar_btn"
    android:id="@+id/sidebar_btn3"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-18dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar_btn"
    android:id="@+id/sidebar_btn2"
    android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-18dp" />
<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sidebar_btn"
    android:id="@+id/sidebar_btn"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-18dp" />
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-176dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"
    android:id="@+id/sidebar"
    android:background="@color/black">

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: make the upper `FrameLayout ` clickable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must add `android:clickable="true"` to  `FrameLayout`

So it can capture the touch or click event when it's on above the button's

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="160dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="-17dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-176dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="-17dp"
    android:id="@+id/sidebar"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:background="@color/black">
```

Comment: Welcome , Do accept as well :) as it indicate correct answer .

Answer (score 1):

try use

```
 bt.setVisible(View.GONE);
```

on the buttons you need to disable and if you need use it again you can use

```
 bt.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
```